How to fix: awssso: error: unrecognized arguments: --login
python --version: Python 3.8.16
aws --version: aws-cli/1.32.96 Python/3.8.16 Darwin/23.4.0 botocore/1.34.96
When I run: awssso --login, I get this error:
usage: awssso [-h] [--version] [--region REGION] [--no-headless] [--no-spinner] {configure,login} ...

awssso: error: unrecognized arguments: --login

I also tried to go through this guide

Try awssso login
